# How to share the Asp.Net Application Variables among severs in a Web Farm environment

Tags: web-farm, application-state, asp.net-session

We can have a persistence storage for Session Variables using `SessionStateMode` as SQLServer. Why don't we need that flexibility for Application Variables? Is it because their size should be very less (common for all users)?

If we are thinking of a .net Web Farm, we might need to make these Application variables to be consistent. Can the SessionStateMode also stores the Application Variables? I see a table `[ASPStateTempApplications]`, but it only have the columns `AppId`, `AppName`.

Comment: What do you mean by application variables? A public static variable inside `Global.asax` for example? Or something like `Application["Foo"] = "Bar";`?

Comment: The application state variables like Application["Foo"] = "Bar"

Comment: I'm installed Redis in both servers, and configured a replication with failover. But if it's possible to use like you asked, it would be simpler than using Redis, I'd like to know if it's possible as well. +1